# Php Numeral Formatting and decimal separator

Tags: javascript, php, yii, cleave

i want to decimal thousand separtor with automatic in Text Input.
example
when write in textinput 5000, i want to automation into 5,000

i have js :

```
var cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
    numeral: true,
    numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
});
```

and i want to use in

```
<td> <?= $form->field($model, '$Payment')->textInput(['maxlength' => 15, 'style' => 'width:120px;'])->label(false) ?></td>
```

so how to use js in text input?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your number text fields a specific class e.g. `formatted-number-input`:

```
<td><?= $form->field($model, '$Payment')
            ->textInput(['maxlength' => 15, 'style' => 'width:120px;', 'class' => 'formatted-number-input'])
            ->label(false) ?></td>
```

You can use this class in your javascript code:

```
new Cleave('.formatted-number-input', {
    numeral: true,
    numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
});
```

Comment: $script = <<<SKRIPT
  new Cleave('.formatted-number-input', {
    numeral: true,
    numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
});
SKRIPT;
$this->registerJs($script);